# Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, security, content-security-policy

I receive this error when trying to load a captcha.  I can only resolve this when I add https://www.google.com/ to the default-src part of my CSP.  My concern is that I'm leaving too wide of an opening to anything with google.com.  My question is, could I add a more specific URL other than https://www.google.com/recaptcha and https://www.google.com/ ?

This default-src block does not work and shows this error

Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/......

```
 "default-src 'self'  https://www.google.com/recpatcha/;
```

This default-src block does work

```
 "default-src 'self'  https://www.google.com/recpatcha/ https://www.google.com/;
```

Comment: Great point!  I went back and added my question.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Try spelling it recaptcha and not recpatcha in your CSP and see if that helps.